# Will Google Picker WebCamView ever work at all?

Tags: android-camera, flash, google-picker

I've been messing around with Google Picker API, and wondering whether it's doomed to be discontinued.  Or is it that I am an early-adopter?

[This complaint about WebCamView ("No CAmera detected")](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-picker-api/L2TVbc2ILD8) is 14 months old, and got just 56 views in all that time.

If Google was taking the product seriously, wouldn't one of their developers respond?

I also tried the WebCamView in an Android tablet without success, and realised that Picker depends on Flash Player 11, which Google dropped support for in Android 26 months ago.

Can anyone say whether this is an omen of future discontinuation of Google Picker, or a temporary set back until they can integrate HTML 5 camera support?

Is there any way to use WebCamView right now? in any browser?, in any OS?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this error, it worked for me on Chrome 38.0.2125.111 (64-bit) on Ubuntu. Any other clues as to why it's failing for you?

Comment: Could you share the code you are using to access it?  Maybe I have misunderstood correct usage.

Comment: I used the standard [hello world sample](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld), swapping out `google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS` with `google.picker.ViewId.WEBCAM`.